# SSRS Multiple Charts on one page - also horizontally / making a dashboard of charts

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to get a whole page of charts (one for every group) on one page in SSRS.
To achieve this vertically, I can just put the chart in a tablix and it does it vertically, but not horizontally.
In other words: It should make a new line only, if the line it is using is already "full".

E.g: to Display 7 Chatrs, where there is space for 3 in one line it should do this:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you set it up as a matix of column and row groupings?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068806/how-to-have-a-child-group-span-across-three-columns/41105247 Make three vertical tables, and use RowNumber with MOD to control which rows are visible in each.