# Show records in three tables with defiate number of rows in each table in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have a table in report like

[image]

I want to show the records in three tables on every page, each table contains only 20 records.

Page1:

[image]

Page2:

[image]

How can I achieve this type of pattern?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried row group expression `=(Fields!ID.Value - 1) Mod 20` and column group expression `=IIf(Fields!ID.Value <= 20, 1, 0)` which splits records into 2 groups not 3 groups.

Comment: refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181556/ssrs-tablix-split-report-into-two-sets-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add the dataset with the below query to get Page number and Table number. You can change the number 20 and 60 as per requirement. In my case, I need 20 records per section and having 3 sections, so total records per page are 60.

```
Select *,(ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( partition by PageNumber order by Id )-1)/20 AS TableNumber   from (
Select (ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (  order by Id )-1)/60 AS PageNumber
,* from Numbers
)Src
```

2)Add the table of one column and select the prepared dataset.

[image]

3)Add `PageNumber` in Group expression for Details group.

[image]

4)Add the Column parent group by right-clicking on detail row. Select Group by `TableNumber`.

[image]

5) Delete the first two rows. Select Delete rows only.
[image]

6) Add one more table and select the ID and Name.

[image]

7) Drag this newly created table into the cell of the previously created table. And increase the size of the table.

[image]

Result:
Each table section contains 20 records. and it will continue in next pages also.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to do this, as a MATRIX style report where the column group is your columns, and as a normal table where you JOIN the data to produce 3 copies of name, ID, and any other fields you want. The MATRIX style is definitely more elegant and flexible, but the normal table might be easier for customers to modify if you're turning the report over to power users.

Both solutions start with tagging the data with PAGE, ROW, and COLUMN information. Note that I'm sorting on NAME, but you could sort on any field. Also note that this solution does not depend on your ID being sequential and in the order you want, it generates it's own sequence numbers based on NAME or whatever else you choose.

In this demo I'm setting RowsPerPage and NumberofColumns as hard coded constants, but they could easily be user selected parameters if you use the MATRIX format.

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 20
DECLARE @Cols INT = 3

;with 
--Fake data generation BEGIN
cteSampleSize as (SELECT TOP 70 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY O.name) as ID 
    FROM sys.objects as O
), cteFakeData as (
    SELECT N.ID, CONCAT(CHAR(65 + N.ID / 26), CHAR(65 + ((N.ID -1) % 26))
        --, CHAR(65 + ((N.ID ) % 26))
        ) as Name
    FROM cteSampleSize as N
), 
--Fake data generation END, real processing begins below
cteNumbered as ( -- We can't count on ID being sequential and in the order we want!
    SELECT D.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY D.Name) as SeqNum
        --Replace ORDER BY D.Name with ORDER BY D.{Whatever field}
    FROM cteFakeData as D --Replace cteFakeData with your real data source
), ctePaged as (
    SELECT D.*
        , 1+ FLOOR((D.SeqNum -1) / (@RowsPerPage*@Cols)) as PageNum
        , 1+ ((D.SeqNum -1) % @RowsPerPage) as RowNum
        , 1+ FLOOR(((D.SeqNum-1) % (@RowsPerPage*@Cols) ) / @RowsPerPage) as ColNum
    FROM cteNumbered as D
) 
--FINAL - use this for MATRIX reports (best)
SELECT * FROM ctePaged ORDER BY SeqNum
```

If you want to use the JOIN method to allow this in a normal table, replace the --FINAL query above with this one. Note that it's pretty finicky, so test it with several degrees of fullness in the final report. I tested with 70 and 90 rows of sample data so I had a partial first column and a full first and partial second.

```
--FINAL - use this for TABLE reports (simpler)
SELECT C1.PageNum , C1.RowNum , C1.ID as C1_ID, C1.Name as C1_Name
    , C2.ID as C2_ID, C2.Name as C2_Name
    , C3.ID as C3_ID, C3.Name as C3_Name
FROM ctePaged as C1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePaged as C2 
        ON C1.PageNum = C2.PageNum AND C1.RowNum = C2.RowNum 
            AND C1.ColNum = 1 AND (C2.ColNum = 2 OR C2.ColNum IS NULL)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePaged as C3 ON C1.PageNum = C3.PageNum 
        AND C1.RowNum = C3.RowNum AND (C3.ColNum = 3 OR C3.ColNum IS NULL)
WHERE C1.ColNum = 1
```